# Spring batch: Stop the batch job if no items are written

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am working on spring batch job. Flow is like below

step 1: (read,process,write on File1)

step 2: mail entries

step 3: (read,process,write on File2)

step 4: mail entries for File2.

I want to skip mailing step if no items are written.

I came across decision control like

```
<batch:decision id="decision" decider="com/Decider">
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="step_3"/>
        <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="step_2"/>
</batch:decision>
```

But how to get write count from previous step to this decision class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JobExecutionDecider#decide`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html#decide-org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution-org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution-) has a `StepExecution` parameter where you can find how many items were written during last step execution ([`StepExecution#getWriteCount`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html#getWriteCount--))